# calling javascript method after codebehind code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I have a repeater in UpdatePanel, and in it is a linkbutton that needs to set some values in a hidden div (display none) and then call javascript method that would make that div visible.

I am using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript and it is calling js method but the problem is that the code behind code is overwritten - code behind code is setting values for some fields from database (in the hidden div) and after it appears the fields are empty. If i click on a different button in repeater in updatepanel the div appears with the values set for a previous click. (the customer demand is that they click on a record in repeater and they can change it in a modal dialog).

how can i get the javascript method to make the modal dialog appear with the proper values?

current code is something like this in oncommand event for a repeater linkbutton

```
  ...
  txtName.Text = row.Name;
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "showEdit", "showModalPanel('pnEdit')", true);
```

Comment: make sure with whatever the html you update from codebehind is in updatepanel

Answer (score 0):

I recently had some issues with getting ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript to work with partial postbacks using an UpdatePanel. Try switching your code to use something like this instead...

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(updPnl, updPnl.GetType(), updPnl.ClientID, "alert('hello world';", True)
```

You also may have to manually update your UpdatePanel on each click so that the hidden div gets the refreshed values. To do this, you'll have to set the UpdateMode on your UpdatePanel to Conditional and then be sure to go back and manually update it whenever you need to in your codebehind.

Comment: it didn't help :(
still the same problem